# Multiprocessing to speed up for loop

Tags: python

Just trying to learn and I"m wondering if multiprocessing would speed 
up this for loop ,.. trying to compare
alexa_white_list(1,000,000 lines) and 
dnsMISP (can get up to 160,000 lines)

Code checks each line in dnsMISP and looks for it in alexa_white_list.
if it doesn't see it, it adds it to blacklist.

Without mp_handler function the code works fine but it takes 
around 40-45 minutes. For brevity, I've omitted all the other imports and
the function that pulls down and unzips the alexa white list.

The below gives me the following error - 
  File "./vetdns.py", line 128, in mp_handler
    p.map(dns_check,dnsMISP,alexa_white_list)
NameError: global name 'dnsMISP' is not defined

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def dns_check():
        awl = []
        blacklist = []
        ctr = 0
        dnsMISP = open(INPUT_FILE,"r")
        dns_misp_lines = dnsMISP.readlines()
        dnsMISP.close()
        alexa_white_list = open(outname, 'r')
        alexa_white_list_lines = alexa_white_list.readlines()
        alexa_white_list.close()
        print "converting awl to proper format"
        for line in alexa_white_list_lines:
            awl.append(".".join(line.split(".")[-2:]).strip())
        print "done"
        for host in dns_misp_lines:
            host = host.strip()
            host = ".".join(host.split(".")[-2:])
            if not host in awl:
                blacklist.append(host)
        file_out = open(FULL_FILENAME,"w")      
        file_out.write("\n".join(blacklist))
        file_out.close()

def mp_handler():
    p = Pool(2)
    p.map(dns_check,dnsMISP,alexa_white_list)


if __name__ =='__main__':
    mp_handler()
```

If I label it as global etc I still get the error.  I'd appreciate any
suggestions!!

Comment: Multiprocessing may not help you much but changing those lists to sets will drastically speed up your membership checks

Comment: `Pool.map` takes a callback function and an iterable as arguments. You clearly haven't read the `multiprocessing` docs, because what you wrote makes no sense. Heck, you pass it arguments that you've never defined, which seems to indicate a basic failure to understand Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for multiprocessing here. In fact this code can be greatly simplified:

```
def get_host_form_line(line):
    return line.strip().split(".", 1)[-1]


def dns_check():
    with open('alexa.txt') as alexa:
        awl = {get_host_from_line(line) for line in alexa}
    blacklist = []
    with open(INPUT_FILE, "r") as dns_misp_lines:
        for line in dns_misp_lines:
            host = get_host_from_line(line)
            if host not in awl:
                blacklist.append(host)
    with open(FULL_FILENAME,"w") as file_out:     
        file_out.write("\n".join(blacklist))
```

Using a set comprehension to create your Alexa collection has the advantage of being `O(1)` lookup time. Sets are similar to dictionaries. They are pretty much dictionaries that only have keys with no values. There is some additional overhead in memory and the initial creation time will likely be slower since the values you put in to a set need to be hashed and hash collisions dealt with but the increase in performance you gain from the faster look ups should make up for it.

You can also clean up your line parsing. `split()` takes an additional parameter that will limit the number of times the input is split. I'm assuming your lines look something like this:

`http://www.something.com` and you want `something.com` (if this isn't the case let me know)

It's important to remember that the `in` operator isn't magic. When you use it to check membership (is an element in the list) what it's essentially doing under the hood is this:

```
for element in list:
    if element == input:
        return True
return False
```

So every time in your code you did `if element in list` your program had to iterate across each element until it either found what you were looking for or got to the end. This was probably the biggest bottleneck of your code.

Comment: you are the man can't thank you enough!  I had to alter a few things because of how much code I left out above and below but the results were mindblowing.  Before my comparison took about 42 minutes and your suggestion about sets dropped it down to less than a minute.   If you know of a good blog or read that really goes into what goes on 'behind the code', i.e. explains hashtables I'd really appreciate it!  Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You tried to read a variable named `dnsMISP` to pass as an argument to `Pool.map`. It doesn't exist in local or global scope (where do you think it's coming from?), so you got a `NameError`. This has nothing to do with `multiprocessing`; you could just type a line with nothing but:

```
dnsMISP
```

and have the same error.

Comment: Clearly he thinks its coming from `dnsMISP = open(INPUT_FILE,"r")`

Comment: Yes, I was just answering your question.    I imagine your answer would have been more helpful if you pointed that out in the answer.